# SQLite error near "PIVOT": syntax error

Tags: sqlite

```
SELECT 
   TYPE, DSMTYPE, REVISION, MODEMTYPE, FWVERSION,
   MAC, TEMP, DATE, TIME, TECHNICIAN 
FROM 
   (SELECT parameterid, parametervalue FROM Product) up 
PIVOT 
   MAX(parametervalue) FOR parameterid IN 
   (TYPE, DSMTYPE, REVISION, MODEMTYPE, FWVERSION, MAC, TEMP, DATE, TIME, TECHNICIAN)) AS pvt
```

SQLite error near "PIVOT": syntax error"

Answer (score 1):

`PIVOT` is not a keyword recognized by SQLite. (It appears to be specific to MSSQL.) The full syntax for SQLite is detailed at:

http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html

Comment: Thanks.   I want to do like this in SqLie.       .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416524/pivot-in-sqlite